# How to test edit function on django? (error django.db.utils.IntegrityError: NOT NULL constraint failed)

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, tdd

i try to write code for editing records and its unit test. here is my code:
**test_view.py**

```
def test_edit_address(self):
    address1 = Address.objects.create(first_name='Edith', last_name='Star', address='Some City', phone_number='123455')
    response = self.client.post(
        reverse('edit', kwargs={'address_id': address1.id}), 
        {'first_name': 'Patrick', 'last_name': 'Stars', 'address': 'Other City', 'phone_number': '0123455'})
    self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 302)
    address1.refresh_from_db()
    self.assertEqual(address1.first_name, 'Patrick')
```

views.py

```
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect, HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import redirect, render
from addressbooksapp.models import Address
from django.contrib import messages

def edit(request, address_id):

  if  request.method == 'POST':
    addresses = Address.objects.get(pk=address_id)

    addresses.first_name = request.POST.get('firstname_text')
    addresses.last_name = request.POST.get('lastname_text')
    addresses.address = request.POST.get('address_text')
    addresses.phone_number = request.POST.get('phone_text')

    addresses.save()
    messages.success(request, ('Record Has Been Edited!'))
    return redirect('home')

  else:
    addresses = Address.objects.get(pk=address_id) 
    return render(request, 'edit.html', {'addresses': addresses})
```

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models

class Address(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    address = models.TextField()
    phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path
from addressbooksapp import views

urlpatterns = [
     path('', views.home_page, name='home'),
     path('delete/<address_id>',views.delete, name='delete'),
     path('edit/<address_id>',views.edit, name='edit'),
]
```

But when run the test i got error "django.db.utils.IntegrityError: NOT NULL constraint failed: addressbooksapp_address.first_name"

Comment: Please add the code of your edit function. It seems that you are not taking into account the fields when creating your object.

Comment: i just added the views.py

Comment: The keys are `first_name`, etc. but your view obtains `firstname_text`...

Answer (score 1):

There is a mismatch between the data you send in the test, and you process in the view. In the test, you send a request with `first_name`, `last_name`, `address`, and `phone_number` as keys. But in the view you process data with `firstname_text`, `lastname_text`, `address_text` and `phone_text`.

You can alter the names, for example in the view with:

```
def edit(request, address_id):

  if  request.method == 'POST':
    addresses = Address.objects.get(pk=address_id)

    addresses.first_name = request.POST['first_name']
    addresses.last_name = request.POST['last_name']
    addresses.address = request.POST['address']
    addresses.phone_number = request.POST['phone_number']

    addresses.save()
    messages.success(request, ('Record Has Been Edited!'))
    return redirect('home')

  else:
    addresses = Address.objects.get(pk=address_id) 
    return render(request, 'edit.html', {'addresses': addresses})
```

I would advice to here use subscripting, so `POST[key]` over using the `.get()` method, since then it will raise an error in case the key is missing.